# Dovecot imap-postlogin failed

Tags: dovecot

In short I am trying to run a bash script which will then update
a mysql database with the last login date/time & last IP for each mailbox.

If i remove the modifications that cause the script to execute the user/mailbox authenticates no problem, but the moment I try to invoke the script authentication starts failing.

I have searched google dead but still cant figure out what im doing wrong
or if there is some issue with the centos 6 rpm's for dovecot.

**my setup in 10-master.conf looks like the following:**

```
service imap-postlogin {  
    executable = script-login /var/www/lighttpd/mail-admin/scripts/lastLogin.sh  
    unix_listener imap-postlogin {  
         user = root 
     } 
} 
service imap {
        executable = imap imap-postlogin
}
```

**My lastLogin.sh bash script has the following in it for debugging**  
    echo "$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S)";  
    echo "User: ${USER}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
    echo "Home: ${HOME}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
    echo "Client IP: ${IP}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
    echo "Server IP: ${LOCAL_IP}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;

**The output to my /tmp/tracker.log is the following**  
User: user@domain.com  
Home: /var/spool/mail/domain.com/user  
Client IP: x.x.x.x  
Server IP: y.y.y.y

**The Authentication Error I am getting now**  
Feb  3 15:23:35 vps dovecot: script-login: Fatal: read() failed: Interrupted system call  
Feb  3 15:23:35 vps dovecot: imap-login: Error: read(imap) failed: Remote closed connection (process_limit reached?)  
Feb  3 15:23:35 vps dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: CANCEL#0111  
Feb  3 15:23:35 vps dovecot: imap-login: Internal login failure (pid=20102 id=1) (internal failure, 1 successful auths): user=, method=PLAIN, rip=x.x.x.x, lip=y.y.y.y.y, TLS, session=

**At the moment for testing the script lastLogin.sh looks like below**  
 #!/bin/sh  
echo "$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S)";  
echo "User: ${USER}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "Password: ${PASS}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "Home: ${HOME}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "Client IP: ${IP}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "Server IP: ${LOCAL_IP}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "Secured: ${SECURED}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "1: ${1}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "2: ${2}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "at: ${@}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
echo "star $*" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1;  
exec "$@";

Comment: Where is the error exactly?

Comment: soz copy spazzed out originally, edited it now

Comment: What happens if you move `user=root` before `unix-listener`, and out of the `imap-postlogin{}` ?

Comment: does your script end with `exec "$@"` ?

Comment: Ok I have edited my post & added the script

Comment: Did you change the location of `user=root` ? that needs to be above `unix_listener`..

Comment: @NickW yes i tried that, no change to the result

Comment: What are the permissions on lastLogin.sh ?

Comment: @NickW For debugging I set the permissions to 777 on that script

Comment: If you set the script to do something much more simple? Just echo "hi" to your log maybe? I really can't see much else that you have done wrong dovecot wise..

Comment: @NickW the main issue that I have gotten to is that if I run this part `executable = imap imap-postlogin` it constantly asks me for the password on the client side.

If i remove that so that it is not running the `imap-postlogin` piece all works perfectly

Comment: Maybe if you remove the `echo "Password: ${PASS}" >> /tmp/tracking.log 2>&1; `, or are you saying that even if the script only echoes Hi to the log, it is still prompting the user/client for their password?

Comment: hmm ok looks like the 2>&1 was stopping errors being reported to the maillog from the script.

So with only echo "hello" (which gets logged to the log file)
I am getting an error now in the maillog
`dovecot: imap(user@domain.com): Post-login script denied access to user user@domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok seems that it is working now, what appeared to have been messing it up was the redirections at the end of the logging `2>&1`. After removing that it all seems to be working 100%.

@NickW Thanks for the help and a pair of fresh eye's :)

Comment: Glad I could help!